Is the C compiler allowed to do out-of-order optimization around an inlined function?
Supposing I have a function foo() and an inline function bar():

inline void bar(void) {
    // do some stuff
}

void foo(void) {
    // some code
    bar();
}

Is the C compiler allowed to rearrange / interleave the sequence of "do some stuff" and "some code" instructions? (Something which would not be allowed if bar was not inlined.)
To make it clear, could the compiler arrange the code to be some instructions of "some code" after instructions of "do some stuff"?
I have a situation where this rearrangement is happening, and I want to know if that is allowed compiler behavior.
Edit: corrected "after instructions"
I'm currently using a C11 compiler.

Welcome to SO. You probable mean "after" instead of "before". Otherwise it would not be any rearrangement.

Does that rearrangement you observed affect the observable behaviour? If not, then I would assume the compiler is allowed to do whatever it likes.

Note that you have an "pure" non-static inline function. There are specific rules for inline definition of a function, and it is expected that an external definition of that function exists. Consider not using inline.

Also kindly I have a situation where this rearrangement is happening - if you consider to ask about that situation, kindly consider asking a complete new question where you describe that specific situation, post a [MCVE], show what you see and present your findings.

It depends on what "do some stuff" means. The C standard defines a side effect as (5.1.2.3):

Accessing a volatile object, modifying an object, modifying a file, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all side effects, which are changes in the state of the execution environment.

Note that it says modifying an object which means a write access to any variable, regardless of if that variable is volatile or not. Furthermore, the term "sequence point" is defined as:

The presence of a sequence point between the evaluation of expressions A and B implies that every value computation and side effect associated with A is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with B.

In case of functions there is at least one sequence point after argument evaluation before the function is called, and one at the end before return. So strictly speaking the above would mean that no re-ordering is allowed what-so-ever.
However, optimizations are allowed to remove side effects that are not "needed":

In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. An actual
implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and
that no needed side effects are produced (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a
volatile object).

So for example something like void f (int y) { int x=y; } contains the side effect of writing to the object x but that value isn't used anywhere, so this whole function could get optimized away without changing the behavior of the program. However if this function definition isn't available to the compiler when it generates the function call code, then it wouldn't be able to assume anything about that function and then it would also be unable to optimize/inline it.
Specifically, optimizations must follow something called "observable behavior", which is defined as follows:

The least requirements on a conforming implementation are:

Accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.
At program termination, all data written into files shall be identical to the result that execution of the program according to the abstract semantics would have produced.
The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place as specified in 7.21.3. The intent of these requirements is that unbuffered or line-buffered output appear as soon as possible, to ensure that prompting messages actually appear prior to a program waiting for
input.

This is the observable behavior of the program.


In plain English:
The compiler is free to re-order the code across a function (inlined or not) or optimize it away entirely, if 1) it can guarantee that the result is the same as it would be without re-ordering/optimizing and 2) there are no volatile variables involved.

thank you for your detailed explanation. They way I understand you then, if bar() is writing to some volatile object (my particular case), the rearrangement is illegal?

@AndresLantschner Some compilers chose to sloppily interpret the standard as "re-ordering different volatile accesses in relation to each other is not allowed". But reading the standard carefully, it actually says that re-ordering anything across a volatile access is not allowed. It would violate sequenced before/after a side effect which isn't possible to optimize out. Similarly, re-ordering of inline assembly/across inline assembly would be similarly dangerous, even though C does not support inline assembly through the standard.

@AndresLantschner It boils down to whether a volatile access should be regarded as a memory barrier or not. Check out this other recent answer by me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78981368/584518

The correct answer is "it depends" on what exactly do some stuff and some code are, but there exists such code in do some stuff and some code that the following answers are true:

Is the C compiler allowed to do out-of-order optimization around an inlined function?

Yes.

Is the C compiler allowed to rearrange / interleave the sequence of "do some stuff" and "some code" instructions?

Yes.

Something which would not be allowed if bar was not inlined.

No, it is allowed irrelevant of inline or not.
To be clear, inline has no affect on any question asked.
inline does nothing, it's only a hint, can be ignored by the compiler. In fact, the compiler can just fully ignore your whole inline definition of the function and use an external definition of the function and still rearrange the code.

To make it clear, could the compiler arrange the code to be some instructions of "some code" before instructions of "do some stuff"?

Yes.

Yes. Maybe. It depends.
The very notion of an optimising compiler is that it produces code that is better than a simplistic translation of the Source program as written, so long as the behaviour of the compiled program is consistent with the defined behaviour of the Source according to the language specification.
The phrase defined behaviour is important. Some behaviours in C are undefined and how the resultant program behaves in those situations may be different between the optimised and un-optimised forms.
In fact the argument for not defining some behaviours is in part a deliberate decision to give optimisers additional freedom to transform the program.
So depending on what // some code and //do some stuff are placeholding for the optimiser may well entirely rearrange, change or omit instructions. That's its purpose.
But if the program and data don't provoke undefined behaviour that should be irrelevant. Avoid provoking undefined behaviour.
Optimising is implemented regarding the language specification under an 'as if'. So while C11 has a notion of sequencing and specifies that the side-effects of everything before a function call (including argument evaluations) take place before the call the optimiser treats that 'as if' and if it helps(*) may cause some of the side-effects to take place after the call if they're not relevant to (in this case) the call to bar().
The optimised program should execute 'as if' those side-effects had taken place before not (necessarily) ensure that they have.
Multi-threading and synchronisation memory barriers had to the constraints on the optimiser. That's beyond the scope of this question but still really only falls under the 'as if' for programs that don't provoke undefined behaviour.
If some code writes to global variables used by bar() then the optimiser either needs to ensure those writes happen before the call or take their effects into account when optimising the (logical) call to bar() in foo(). Of course if bar() is called elsewhere in the program the instructions it translates to may be different in each case depending on the surrounding code.
(*) what helps is defined by what the optimiser is trying to optimise. Optimising for code size will likely result in bar() not being inlined if //do some stuff is small or inlined if the functional call overhead increases program size. The more common case is to be optimising for execution speed and that tends to favour inlining.

Optimization has to be consistent with the observable behavior of a program, not the defined behavior. The C standard defines behavior in a notional abstract machine, but the optimizer is not required to conform to the behavior defined in that abstract machine.

Surely 'as if' encompasses (relevantly) observable and (relevantly) consistent if observable means observable within the execution of the program. Things like debuggers allow us to observe outside what the optimiser is seeking to be consistent with.

“As if” is mentioned in the sixth paragraph, and it is not defined or explained there. Or maybe some part of a sentence in there is supposed to explain it, but it is unclear. What would somebody learning about this for the first time make of the phrase “as if”? “As if” what? Further, what is explained is wrong. Side effects and observable behavior are different things. Modifying an object, as in an assignment, is a side effect, but it is not observable behavior (unless the object is volatile, but that is a different matter). I am sorry, but this answer is wrong.

I'm struggling to understand difference between consistent with defined behaviour (under an as-if) according to the language specification and observable behaviour in a notional abstract machine. An example would help.
Side-effects are relevant to re-ordering but under (either as-if and observable notions) only if they have some relevant consequence.

The sentence “The optimised program should execute 'as if' those side-effects had taken place before not (necessarily) ensure that they have” is false. If C source code contains a = 3;, and the program would execute that, an optimized version of the program is not required to execute as if the side effect of storing 3 in a had occurred. In fact, the standard does not use “as if” in the paragraph that allows optimization. That is a popular rephrasing…

… What the C standard actually does is specify rules for interpreting C programs as behavior in an abstract machine and that the program implemented by a C implementation must have the same observable behavior as some execution of the program (there may be multiple allowed possibilities) in the abstract machine, where the observable behavior is that accesses to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine, all data written into files by program termination is identical that that the abstract machine would have produced, and…

… the input and output dynamics of interactive devices take place as specified in C 2018 7.21.3, which discusses external files (which may be physical devices, like terminals). It does not say that optimization must respect side effects, other than those that are part of observable behavior. Nor does it say the behavior of the implemented program has to be “consistent” with the defined behavior in the abstract machine, whatever “consistent” means.

Also, this is bad advice: “Avoid provoking undefined behaviour.” The C standard does not define a walled garden where you may only play inside the constraints it gives. The C standard defines a core language that is intended to be extended. It is an open city that provides public transit, water, electricity, and other services, but leaves you free to build your own machines inside it or even to leave the city and come back. Using graphics library is undefined behavior by the C standard. Would you tell people to avoid calling a graphics library? To avoid using network communications?…

… To avoid calling subroutines in other languages? To avoid calling operating system routines? All of those are undefined behavior as that term is used in the C standard.

Yes, the compiler is allowed to rearrange or interleave the sequence of instructions, including those from an inline function like bar(), with the rest of the code in foo().
